# PDF file does not get open from ShellExecute function in Visual Studio, C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, pdf, mfc, cmd

I am trying to open "Read Me.pdf" file after installation of my App finished.

I am trying to open this PDF file using

```
ShellExecute( NULL, _T("open"), csReadMe, NULL, csFileDir, SW_SHOWNORMAL );
```

and also tried

```
ShellExecute( NULL, NULL, csReadMe, NULL, csFileDir, SW_SHOWNORMAL );
```

May be, I have an issue regarding Adobe Reader 11.02 version, because in the earlier version of Adobe Reader that file was opening, while in AR 11.02 the Process is displaying in the `Task Manager` while `ShellExecute()` call, but Adobe Reader does not launch.

I am using VS 2012 with Win 8.

If I explicitly open that file or from the command prompt, then its easily open.

I dint find that what is going wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have work around and find conclusion that if my App run as Administrator then Adobe does not launch with given "Read Me.pdf" file, specifically in the Win8 with Adobe Reader 11.02 version. Now, I got stuck again, what should I do next to over come from this issue. Need Help.

Comment: What's the return code of ShellExecute when it fails ? What does GetlastError() return if ShellExecute fails ?

Comment: GetLastError() return 0, It means ShellExecute() execute successfully.

Comment: And, the process of the Adobe Reader can also view in the Task Manager, but the PDF file does not get open.

Comment: Don't use `GetLastError()`. You want the return code from the function call. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx