# ShellExecute in MFC does not open Adobe XI

Tags: c++, pdf, mfc

note: I already looked at the following question but it provided no insight: [PDF file does not get open from ShellExecute function in Visual Studio, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679337/pdf-file-does-not-get-open-from-shellexecute-function-in-visual-studio-c)

I have the same problem as the poster in the above question.

Trying to open a PDF file from an MFC Application using ShellExecute. Adobe XI on Win 8 64 bit system.

```
hReturn = ::ShellExecuteA(NULL,"open",sPath,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

`sPath` is a CString although I've tried alternatives with the same result. I've also tried `SW_SHOW`, `SW_SHOWNORMAL`. ShellExecute returns 42 when I cast the HINSTANCE to an int. I understand that means it opens successfully.

In fact, if I watch the task manager when executing the command, Adobe Reader opens in response in Task Manger but the Adobe window never opens.

When I exit my application, Adobe is still open.

If I try to open the target PDF file, the O/S says it can't be opened because it is already open in another application. When I "End Task" on the Adobe Reader in task manager, it frees up the file.

If I then click on the file, it opens fine in Adobe Reader.

So, I'm inferring from this that the ShellExecute is launching Adobe, that it is getting the right file, and that the file is, indeed, readable.

I've also confirmed that ShellExecute is working by directly referencing a txt file. It opens fine in Notepad.

```
hReturn = ::ShellExecuteA(NULL,"open","d:\\develop\\readme.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried just `SW_SHOW`. have you tried omitting the `"open"` verb.

Comment: Yes I have tried SW_SHOW.

Comment: I have just discovered that if I run my app as administrator, it works fine. And then... from then on, it works fine no matter how I run it. Does this make any sense at all to anybody? It solves my problem on this particular machine but when I distribute it, I'm afraid it will be flaky.

Comment: I'll try without "open" too, although now I'm not sure how to make it not work. I'll try a reboot and see if it goes back to the not-working state.

Answer (score 2):

try disable "Protected mode"

[Adobe Reader - Protected Mode](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/protectedmode.html)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known problem with opening a PDF file on Win8 via ShellExecuteEx.  I had the same issue with an installer that would try to open a PDF at the end of the install process.  On Win7 it worked fine.  On Win8, it displayed the symptoms you describe.  I was able to track it down to a problem with elevated privileges on our install program.  I'm not sure why that would adversely affect things, but, it did.  As an alternative, we looked at opening the file as an HTML document instead.  We are still looking for a better solution.